# output placement of first input python

Tags: python, input, output

When executing the following Python code:

```
print('hello')
print(input('name'))
print(input('age'))
```

The input box will be placed above the printing of 'hello'. After providing input, it will appear below the printing of hello, and any more input boxes will also be placed under any previous output.
My question is, how to make this first input box also position correctly (below the printing of hello) in the output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Manually add a newline character `\n`

Comment: Where do you suggest i add it, none of my attempts achived what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code in Python 3.5 under windows and it works. However if it doesn't for you it's because the stdout isn't being flushed until the input function. Try this:

```
import sys
print('hello')
sys.stdout.flush()
print(input('name'))
print(input('age'))
```

This will "reload" the standart output after the printing of hello.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me either, but thanks for the try!

Comment: Oh, im sorry. as I can't replicate the error idk what else to try. Good luck!